# How do I display a random image that stays the same once first displayed?

Tags: php, wordpress, random

I have a WordPress site. On this site, I am trying to create a dice-rolling game that displays above specific post formats. Here is the way it will work:

There will be a directory on my server. In the directory, there are six different images, each of one dice side. One will be a picture of a dice side with one dot, another picture will have two dots, etc.

The "rolling" of the dice is simulated by using PHP to display a random image from that directory. But there's a catch...

Once the post that displays a "rolling" of the dice is created, I want that particular random image that is picked to be stuck to that post, so that no matter how many times you refresh the page, that same "roll" will be associated with that post.

In essence, every visitor will see the same image, the same "roll", no matter what server is used, or whether they've refreshed the page or not. If the image that shows up is "five", then all users will see "five" even if they refresh the page.

Although it is possible to do this by playing Random Number God and just creating an algorithm with the post time, post ID, and other things in order to get a single "random" number for each post based on post meta, I would like to know if it would be easier to make it so that the image chosen was stored in the database instead.

It's likely that there are other options that I may not have thought of. If there are, I would certainly like to hear about them. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want cookies, users should have to be registered, are they?

Comment: I don't have to associate the "roll" with users. I just have to associate them with posts. Every post has an ID and a time when posted. I could use those if needed.

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] the Question and clarify things a bit. You say in a comment bellow *"I need the "roll" to stay the same no matter what."* and I don't get the relation between `posts` and `visitors/users`. What happens when I visit one post and what happens when you visit the same post? You have to differentiate users somewhat, or the first visit set the random image for all subsequent visits? ***And please, don't clarify in comments, improve the Question instead*** ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by making use of PHP sessions. It will essentially store the result as a cookie in the user's browser.

When the page's reloaded, check for the dice in the appropriate session variable, if it's available show that or generate something new.

When a user visits for the first time, he gets an image (anything b/w 1 and 6) and this info's stored in the cookie. On subsequent refreshes, the same image is shown as the server looks for the cookie before generating a new image.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem with this is that the image displayed is only the same for that user, not all users-- and if they delete their cookies, the image will change again. No, this is not at all an effective solution. I need the "roll" to stay the same no matter what.

Comment: Or you can populate a hidden form element using the current "roll". And use this information to generate the dice whenever the page's loaded.

Comment: Manikandan - I have no idea what you're talking about, and I don't know if that solves my problem either. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Have an `<input type="hidden" name="dice" value="">` in your page. Populate its value using the dice roll's value on first load. On subsequent loads, look for this value using $_POST and show the relevant number if its exists. Generate a new dice if it doesn't.